# how to convert List<List<Object>> to List<Object> in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Future<List<Product>> getproduct() async {
    final invoice = await isar.invoices.where().findAll();
    var p = invoice.map((e) {
      var a = e.products;

      return a;
    }).toList();

    return p ;
}
```

returns `Future<List<List< Product >>>` and only want `Future<List< Product >>` how to remove outer list.

Comment: check `Iterable.expand` method

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **pskink** you can use `Iterable.expand` like this:

```
final invoice = await isar.invoices.where().findAll();
var p = invoice.map((e) => e.products).expand((element) => element).toList();
```